# How can I reload an image on a time interval?

Tags: javascript, image, reload

I have two images that need to be reloaded in x time. I tried to do it this way:

```
<script>
 function srcreload(){
     imguser=document.getElementsByName("userimage")[0];
     imgme=document.getElementsByName("me")[0];
     imguser.src=imguser.src;imgme.src=imgme.src;setTimeout("srcreload()",15000);};
     setTimeout("srcreload()",15000);
</script>
  <img src="somesrc" name="userimage">
  <img src="someothersrc" name="me">
```

Why isn't this working and how do I fix it? I got it to work one time, but then I must have changed something because it is no longer working.

Comment: Please elaborate what "does not work" means and what browser you are using.

Comment: there is an unnecessary `{` in the end of your javascript

Comment: im using chrome, but i need it to work in all major browsers (IE, Chrome, Firefox). And it doesnt work idk why...
Removed the unnecessary {

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use `var`.
2. Don't pass a string to `setTimeout`, but a function.
3. Indent properly.

If you indent nicely, you see an extraneous `}`, which doesn't belong there.

```
var url = "...";

function srcreload() {
    var imguser = document.getElementsByName("userimage")[0];
    var imgme = document.getElementsByName("me")[0];

    var random = "?" + Math.random();

    imguser.src = url + random;
    imgme.src = url + random;

   setTimeout(srcreload, 15000);
}

setTimeout(srcreload, 15000);
```

Comment: Strings can be sent to setTimeout it will be evaluated.

Comment: i tryed your solution right now and the problem doesnt seem to lie there. In my page the code it all nicely set up, with no extrauous }. Stil, the images wont update.

Comment: @Tobias: I know, but it's a **very bad** practice.

Comment: @pimvdb: i did try it. but it stil didn't work.
oh wait.. you edited it, just a sec, ill try it again

Comment: it did work, but it afects the images.. they look diferent after they are reloaded

Comment: @jony: In my example I used a random image provider so that you can see it is indeed reloaded. I don't know what you're after then; it should reload, shouldn't it?

Comment: try with these images and you will see my problem:
<img name="me" border="0" width="80" src="http://alexhgfdalex.chatango.com/i?15"/>
<img name="userimage" border="0" width="80" src="http://alexhgfdalex.chatango.com/i?15"/>

Comment: it did reload, but it also changes the image (my image)- yours doesnt seem to be afected

Comment: i see what is happening: the generated number is overwriting the default url parameter of my image

Comment: @jony: Ah - your provider uses the `?` already. I don't think you can use the cache trick then. http://jsfiddle.net/tZQ4c/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
imguser.src=imguser.src;
imgme.src=imgme.src;
```

does these do lines makes any sense, same value is being copied?

Comment: I guess it makes the browser download the file again, but I'm not sure if it's a good practice (it may just use the cache).

Comment: i have already used the same kind of trick on iframes to make them reload and it doesn't use the cached copy.

Comment: ahh XD its just slipping through my fingers! it works great with the question mark, but not with the "#"